# EF Core - Using DbSet dynamically with generics

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, autofac

I have an interface that is being attached in my DI

```
builder.RegisterType<TaskTempo>().As<ITaskTempo>();
```

This is being done because `ITaskTempo` is dynamic and could be one of multiple objects, but sharing same interface.

Anyway, I have `DbContext` where I map the `DbSet` with entity manually

```
// DI register
builder.RegisterType<MapperFor890>().As<IEntityMapper>();

// ...
// DbContext

public partial class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IEntityMapper _entityMapper;

    // Please not that I do not want to manually add all of diff implementations of ITaskTempo here
    // public virtual DbSet<TaskTempo1> TaskTempo { get; set; }


    public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options, IEntityMapper mapper)
        : base(options)
    {
        _entityMapper = mapper;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Map Entities
        _entityMapper.Map(modelBuilder, this);
    }
}

// ...
// EntityMapper
public class MapperFor890 : IEntityMapper
{
    public void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskTempo1>(entity => 
        {
            // Map here the properties
        });
    }
}
```

Then, I am able to fetch data from `EfRepository`:

```
// Global Repository
public class EfRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;
    protected readonly ILogger<EfRepository<TEntity>> Logger;

    public EfRepository(DbContext context,
        ILogger<EfRepository<TEntity>> logger)
    {
        Context = context;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        Logger.LogDebug($"Finding '{typeof(TEntity).Name}' with predicate");
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }
}

// TaskTempo Repository
public class TaskTempoRepository<TTaskTempo> : EfRepository<TTaskTempo>, ITaskScanRepository<TTaskTempo> where TTaskTempo : class, ITaskTempo
{
    public MyDBContext DbContext => Context as MyDBContext;

    public TaskScanRepository(MyDBContext context, ILogger<TaskScanRepository<TTaskTempo>> logger) : base(context,logger)
    {
    }
}

// DI injection
builder.RegisterType<TaskTempo1>().As<ITaskTempo>();
builder.RegisterType<TaskTempoRepository<ITaskTempo>>().As<ITasTempoRepository<ITaskTempo>>();
```

Once I fetch

```
_taskTempoRepository.Find(t => t.Id = 3);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'ITaskTempo' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Comment: do you have a key on your TaskTempo model? Can you share your TaskTempo model code?

Comment: You should never pass interface as generic argument to `Set<TEntity>()` method. EF Core works with concrete entity types, not interfaces or base classes. In what you have shown, the problem seems to be `ITaskTempo` here `builder.RegisterType<TaskTempoRepository<ITaskTempo>>()`

Comment: @AussieJoe just an Entity object, no key. But why?

Comment: @fiskolin is your model annotated "Keyless" ? If not, it expects a key.